# How to properly resize the most outside view in a custom keyboard extension ViewController using swift 3?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I have a function that sets the height of a `custom keyboard` extension, depending on the phone. I originally just tried this in viewDidLoad():

```
    self.view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100)
```

This didn't seem to work, so I made a function:

```
func updateHeightOfView() {
    var currentKeyboardInView: String!
        if currentViewHeightConstraint != nil {
            view.removeConstraint(currentViewHeightConstraint!)
        }
        currentViewHeightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: desiredHeight)
        view.addConstraint(currentViewHeightConstraint!)
}
```

that way when the screen changes it's orientation, I resize the view. The second block of code works perfectly, but it throws warnings of layoutConstraints, so I was wondering why the first block of code isn't working, and if there is an easier way to UPDATE constraints of the height property of a view rather than add and remove them. This view is the most outside view in the viewController.

Here's the warning the second block spits out:

```
[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000298b00 App.KeyboardAccessoryView:0x7fdc00b1bfe0.height == 258   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000297e80 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' App.KeyboardAccessoryView:0x7fdc00b1bfe0.height == 216   (active)>"
Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000298b00 App.KeyboardAccessoryView:0x7fdc00b1bfe0.height == 258   (active)>
```

Answer (score 0):

As much detail you given here according to this I think where ever you set height of this view it is not static constant value but in view didload you are setting constant value for its height. So that's by it is not working.

In second block you are getting warning because may be your view is getting height from more than one way. To check this in updathHeight method just remove the constraint , don't add and try to run.

Exact solution could be given only looking on your constraints.

Comment: in viewDidLoad, I just call updateHeightOfView(), which is the second code block in my initial post. I don't se any other constraints to the View, but items inside the view, which only consist of stackviews and buttons, have top/left/right/bottom of 0.